# Play scala Oauth Twitter example and redirect

Tags: scala, playframework, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

The play example for using Oauth and Twitter is show below.

In the Play Framework I am still learning how to use redirects and routes.  How would you set up the routes file and the Appliction.scala file to handle this redirect?

```
Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession("token" -> t.token, "secret" -> t.secret)
```

Would the routes be something like this?

```
GET /index  controllers.Application.index(String, String)
```

Link to Play Framework documentation with the example code http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaOAuth

```
object Twitter extends Controller {

  val KEY = ConsumerKey("xxxxx", "xxxxx")

  val TWITTER = OAuth(ServiceInfo(
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", KEY),
    false)

  def authenticate = Action { request =>
    request.queryString.get("oauth_verifier").flatMap(_.headOption).map { verifier =>
      val tokenPair = sessionTokenPair(request).get
      // We got the verifier; now get the access token, store it and back to index
      TWITTER.retrieveAccessToken(tokenPair, verifier) match {
        case Right(t) => {
          // We received the authorized tokens in the OAuth object - store it before we proceed
          Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession("token" -> t.token, "secret" -> t.secret)
        }
        case Left(e) => throw e
      }
    }.getOrElse(
      TWITTER.retrieveRequestToken("http://localhost:9000/auth") match {
        case Right(t) => {
          // We received the unauthorized tokens in the OAuth object - store it before we proceed
          Redirect(TWITTER.redirectUrl(t.token)).withSession("token" -> t.token, "secret" -> t.secret)
        }
        case Left(e) => throw e
      })
  }

  def sessionTokenPair(implicit request: RequestHeader): Option[RequestToken] = {
    for {
      token <- request.session.get("token")
      secret <- request.session.get("secret")
    } yield {
      RequestToken(token, secret)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the reasons I had so many intermittent problems with routes and redirect was a combination of the versions of play, version of scala and the version of ScalaIDE for Eclipse.  Using Play version 2.2.3, scala version 2.10.4 and ScalaIDE version 2.10.x solved the routes and redirect problems.

The following import statements are needed for the Twitter example.

```
import play.api.libs.oauth.ConsumerKey
import play.api.libs.oauth.ServiceInfo
import play.api.libs.oauth.OAuth
import play.api.libs.oauth.RequestToken
```

Answer (score 0):

If your route is like this:

`GET /index  controllers.Application.index(param1:String, param2:String)`

Then the reverse route would look like this:

`routes.Application.index("p1", "p2")`

Which would result in something like this:

`/index?param1=p1&param2=p2`

Make sure that the documentation you are looking at is of the correct version, for `2.2.x` you would need this url: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaOAuth

Comment: EECOLOR your code got rid of the routing error I was getting.  When I put the example code in a file called twitter.scala I get a redirect error message on this line but it works if I put the code in the Application.scala file Redirect(routes.Application.index).withSession("token" -> t.token, "secret" -> t.secret)".  Do all the **Action { request =>** have to be in the Application.scala file?

Comment: No they don't. In most cases your classes should extend `Controller` to make sure you have all HTTP related tools available. It is however not mandatory, look in the source of `Controller` to see what it makes available.